# Calling script from resource folder in Jenkins shared folder

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

Have PowerShell script in resource folder and want to use this script in shared library .groovy script which is under vars folder. Is it there a way to do so??

Answer (score 6):

To run a PS script from the resources dir of your shared library, assuming `psScript1.ps1` is in `your-shared-library/resources/`:

```
powershell "${libraryResource 'psScript1.ps1'}"
```

This works great, however, it doesn't let you pass in parameters. I can't seem to find a one-line way to do it.

Building on @christopher's answer, here's a two-line solution:

```
writeFile file: 'tempFile.ps1', text: "${libraryResource 'psScript1.ps1'}"
powershell './tempFile.ps1 -yourParam $yourParam'
```

*In my testing, I found the `./` to start the temp file path to be required.*

Comment: To add to this, if you need to dot-source any scripts in your other scripts, I wasn't able to do it directly. I have to put them in the workspace first, even though they're in the `/resources` dir. ```helperFiles = ['list', 'of', 'files']

  helperFiles.each {
    writeFile file: it, text: "${libraryResource it}"
  }
```

Comment: Works under Linux systems too - just replace `.ps1` with `.sh`, `powershell` with `sh` and skip the `-yourParam` switch (`sh "./tempFile.sh ${yourParam}"`).

Comment: [Using Resource Files from a Jenkins Shared Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV7roTXrEqg) expands on this by creating a custom "loadLinuxScript" step (or in your case loadPowerShellScript) to wrap writeFile. It's fundamentally the same idea but having a custom name for the step makes the usage/intent clearer.

Comment: @RyanTaylor I like that! I think I tried to build something similar back then, but didn’t finish.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `libraryResource(file-in-resources)` ([docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#-libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library)) to load a file from the library resources as a text. That you can write to your workspace with `writeFile` ([docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#-writefile-write-file-to-workspace)) and execute.

As the library is checked out somewhere next to your workspace you can maybe execute it directly.

Comment: `you can maybe execute it directly`
It's theoretically possible to do this if you know where the library files are, but it's intentionally obfuscated by Jenkins. I could be wrong, but I don't think it's reliable to try to access them directly in code. They are physically there if you go to the `workspaces` dir where all the jobs live, but I don't think it's guaranteed to be the same structure every time. Hence, the native functionality of `libraryResource` is guaranteed to give you the file.